# Put a book in several categories (Django)

Tags: python, django, web

I have a model named "book" and a model named "BookCategoty". how i can assign infinite category ForgienKeys? for books that fall into several categories.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use models.ManyToManyField(Model_name)